# Неправильная кодировка при парсинге сайта с помощью bs4 и requests

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup, bs4

только что спарсил сайт, цены выводит нормально но текст на русском языке как-то по другому выводит, вот результат:

```
ÐÐ°ÑÐ°
ÐÐ°ÐºÑ. ÑÐµÐ½Ð°
Ð±ÑÐµÐ¼ ÑÐ¾ÑÐ³Ð¾Ð²
ÐÐ°Ð¿Ð¸ÑÐ°Ð»Ð¸Ð·Ð°ÑÐ¸Ñ
31.01.2021
$34 288
$52 754 542 671
$616 452 744 533
30.01.2021
$34 834
$65 141 828 798
$637 924 573 284
29.01.2021
$38 406
$117 894 572 511
$638 768 671 362
28.01.2021
$31 891
$78 948 162 368
$589 083 045 078
27.01.2021
$32 564
$62 576 762 015
$566 417 413 554
26.01.2021
$32 794
$60 255 421 470
$606 169 260 387
25.01.2021
$34 802
$59 897 054 838
$602 350 097 075
```

Вот код самого парсера:

```
    import requests
    
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
    site = "https://newscryptocoin.com/2021/02/01/kurs-bitkoina-bitcoin-btc-na-segodnja-01-fevralja/"
    
    
    answer = requests.get(site).text
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(answer, "lxml")
    
    
    soup.find("tbody")
    td = soup.find_all("td")
    k = 1
    for i in td:
        print(i.text)
```

Comment: Укажите кодировку UTF-8 или Windows-1251

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
answer = requests.get(site).text
                            ^^^^
```

Вы зря отрезали информацию о кодировке, которая есть в `html` и оставили только текст. Достаточно поменять одну строчку в вашем коде и всё будет нормально, `BeautifulSoup` сам разберётся с кодировкой, нужно просто не лишать его информации о ней:

```
answer = requests.get(site).content
                            ^^^^^^^
```

Теперь у `BeautifulSoup` есть такая информация о кодировке, содержащаяся в получаемой странице:

```
<html lang="ru-RU"><head><meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Вывод после изменения:

```
Дата
Макс. цена
Объем торгов
Капитализация
31.01.2021
$34 288
$52 754 542 671
$616 452 744 533
...
```

Comment: Спасибо, что выручили

Comment: @ДмитрийВинокуров, [как принято говорить "спасибо" на SO (StackOverflow) ;)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/348814)